# Use postgres function timestamp in JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I try to group by date only, column active_to is timestamp so it has time also. This query works in pgAdmin but JpaRepository seems to have problem even if it is native query. How can I modify this query to work using JpaRepository?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT o.active_to::timestamp::date, count(o) as sum from work_order o group by o.active_to::timestamp::date order by o.active_to::timestamp::date  asc limit 7", nativeQuery = true)
```

I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
  Position: 19
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use : because this is the character that starts a named parameter.

You have to use cast.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT cast(cast(o.active_to as timestamp) as date), count(o) as sum " +
               "from work_order o group by cast(cast(o.active_to as timestamp) as date) " +  
               "order by cast(cast(o.active_to as timestamp) as date) asc limit 7",
               nativeQuery = true)
```

Cast and :: are similar. Read more about here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS